# Pass Oracle clobs from and to Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql, clob

I am writing a piece of code to apply a very customer specific encoding to XML data. At first I tried to do this using only PL-SQL, but ran into very poor performance (1 hour for 160 records). After that I tried it with only java, wich gave great performance (400.000 records in 1 minute)

Now I want to see how the performance is when I build the code in Java and load it into the database.

For that I have the following code:

```
create or replace and compile java source named XmlNumericEncoder as
public class XmlNumericEncoder {
    public static String encode(String xmlstring) { 
        String xmlstring_out = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < xmlstring.length(); i++){
            char ch = xmlstring.charAt(i);        

            if ((int)ch  >=  192 && (int)ch <= 255){
               xmlstring_out += "&#" + (int)ch + ";"; 
            } else {
               xmlstring_out += ch;
            }
        }
        return xmlstring_out;
    } 
}



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION XmlNumericEncoder(xmlstring varchar2)
        RETURN String
        AS LANGUAGE JAVA
        NAME 'XmlNumericEncoder.encode(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
```

This code can be executed the following way:

```
select XmlNumericEncoder('Böhmer') from dual;
```

The problem I'm now facing is that I need the function to execute on larger parts of data, stored in clobs. I know there is a java.sql.Clob class, and I can get it to work as a input parameter, but I can't seem to get it to work as a output parameter, I keep running into nullpointer exceptions.

This is the code I was working with:

```
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class XmlNumericEncoder {
    public static Clob encode(Clob xmlclob) throws SQLException { 
        String xmlstring_out = "";
        Clob xmlclob_out = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < xmlclob.length(); i++){
            char ch = xmlclob.getSubString(i,1).charAt(1);        

            if ((int)ch  >=  192 && (int)ch <= 255){
               xmlstring_out += "&#" + (int)ch + ";"; 
            } else {
               xmlstring_out += ch;
            }
        }
        int setString = xmlclob_out.setString(0, xmlstring_out);

        return xmlclob_out;
    }
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Where do you get null pointer exceptions? Could you post your stack trace?

Comment: Seems obvious you are getting nullpointer exception : `Clob xmlclob_out = null;`, you never instantiate any Clob object in your code.

Comment: I know, but how should that be done? "java.sql.Clob is abstract; cannot be instantiated", should I send a input and output clob from oracle?

Comment: There must be something wrong in your PL/SQL code if adding a layer of java improves performance. The same function rewritten in PL/SQL is faster on the 2 instances I have tested (9ir2 and 11gr2). In 11gr2 with PL/SQL optimization, the result is 100 times faster in PL/SQL. Here's my setup: http://pastebin.com/YCeGwUYg

Answer (score 2):

Similar to your issue, I had a requirement to insert a clob into an Oracle database from a Java program running within the database. None of the answers here quite worked for me.

I eventually found solution, the trick being to use oracle.sql.CLOB

This the approach I discovered:

```
create table test_clob (
    c clob
);

create or replace and compile java source named java_clob_insert as

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import oracle.sql.CLOB;
import java.io.Writer;

public class JavaClobInsert {

    public static void doInsert () {

        try {

            //create the connection and statement
            Connection oracleConn =
                (new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver()).defaultConnection();

            String stmt = "INSERT INTO test_clob values (?)";

            PreparedStatement oraclePstmt = oracleConn.prepareStatement(stmt);

            //Imagine we have a mysql longtext or some very long string
            String s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 32768; i++) {
                s += i % 10;
            }

            //Initialise the Oracle CLOB
            CLOB clob;
            clob = CLOB.createTemporary(oracleConn, true, CLOB.DURATION_CALL);

            //Good idea to check the string is not null before writing to clob
            if (s != null) {
                Writer w = clob.setCharacterStream( 1L );
                w.write(s);
                w.close();
                oraclePstmt.setClob(1, clob);
            } else {
                oraclePstmt.setString(1, "");
            }

            //clean up
            oraclePstmt.executeUpdate();
            oracleConn.commit();
            oraclePstmt.close();
            oracleConn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
/

create or replace procedure clob_insert as language java name 
    'JavaClobInsert.doInsert()';    
/

begin
    clob_insert;
end;
/

select *
from   test_clob;
```

Answer (score 0):

The NullpointerException is due to the line

```
Clob xmlclob_out = null;
```

I don't really know how to initialize a Clob in this case. In [a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html) you use your connection, you do something like

```
Clob myClob = this.con.createClob();
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get hold of a JDBC connection. From within a Java stored procedure you should do it like this :

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
```

The you can use the `createClob()` method of `java.sql.Connection` to instantiate an object to represent your CLOB.

See [The API documentation of Clob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createClob%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've tried that, but this doesn't seem to be the way when the java code is actually stored in the Oracle database. I've modified the code into:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED MAGMA."XMLNUMERICENCODER" AS
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class XmlNumericEncoder {

public static Clob encode(Clob xmlstring) throws SQLException { 

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");

    String xmlstring_out = "";
    Clob xmlclob_out = conn.createClob();
    for (int i = 0; i < xmlstring.length(); i++){
        char ch = xmlstring.getSubString(i,1).charAt(1);        
        if ((int)ch  >=  192 && (int)ch <= 255){
           xmlstring_out += "&#" + (int)ch + ";"; 
        } else {
           xmlstring_out += ch;
        }
    }
    int setString = xmlclob_out.setString(0, xmlstring_out);

    return xmlclob_out;
}
```

}

But when I try to compile it, I get the following errors:

XMLNUMERICENCODER:12: cannot find symbol

symbol  : method createClob()

location: interface java.sql.Connection

Clob xmlclob_out = conn.createClob();

I've also tried creating the connection like this: Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/dbname", "username", "password")

but that gave me the same error.

It seems a bit odd to me that I need to create a connections, since I'm already in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'know it's an old post but..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "MyJava"
as 
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import oracle.sql.BLOB;
import oracle.sql.CLOB;

public class MyJava{
    public static CLOB myClob() {
        try {
            String outputString = "this is my text to write in the CLOB";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
            CLOB clob = CLOB.createTemporary(conn, false, BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
            clob.setString(1L, outputString);
            return clob;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
/
```

and then the wrapper for PL/SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_JAVA_CLOB() RETURN clob
AS language java
 name 'MyJava.myClob() return oracle.sql.CLOB';
/
```